# How to increase the page height by X pixels by using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Assume an HTML page:

```
<html>
  <body>
     .. html content (outside of our control) ..
     .. javascript block ..
     .. some more html content (outside of our control) ..
  </body>
</html>
```

Assume further that the only part of the HTML page that we're able to control is a javascript block in the middle of the page.

Using that javascript block, how do I increase the total page height by 150 pixels by "padding" the bottom of the page?

If I could alter the HTML a simple solution would be:

```
<html>
  <body>
     .. html content (outside of our control) ..
     .. javascript block ..
     .. some more html content (outside of our control) ..
     <div style="height: 150px; clear: both;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But how do I achieve this only by using the javascript block?

The ideal solution should be cross-browser compatible and 100 % inline (that is using no javascript library).

**Update #1:** The javascript block has access to the entire DOM of the page.

**Update #2:** The total length of the page (before altering the DOM) varies.

**Update #3:** Assume that no javascript library (such as the otherwise excellent jQuery) can be used.

Comment: Is your javascript going in an iframe, or would you have dom access to the entire page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated code:

```
var space = document.createElement('div');
space.style.height = "150px";
space.style.clear = "both";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(space);
```

Comment: This should work no matter what the length of the page is.  I'm out of votes, or I'd vote it up.  I was about to post basically the same thing.

Comment: the original code only produced an absolute height, this is the updated version

Answer (score 1):

Can you generate DOM elements via javascript and simply add that div to the bottom?

I'd vote for cobbal If I had any rep.. heh.

Answer (score 0):

$('body').append($('<div style="height: 150px; clear: both;"></div>'));

maybe

Comment: Ah sorry John, looks like the code formatting added escape chars which I failed to notice. Sorry about that. As an aside this answer came up as a 'low quality post' in the review section, might be worth expanding on it if possible.