# Increase content size of UIWebView using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a translucent toolbar over the bottom of my `UIWebView`.  The trouble is, if there is a link at the bottom of the page, I can't press it because the webview will always bounce back down to the bottom.

I don't want to shrink the webview and use a solid colour toolbar, and `UIWebView`s interface doesn't open much up.

What I would like to do, ideally, is to actually increase the size of the web page by one toolbar height, so that I can scroll that extra bit and have all the content above the toolbar, but when scrolling down I will be able to see the page content through the toolbar.  I could use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` function of `UIWebView`.

I'm very rusty on JavaScript- is it possible for me to do this?  Increase the window height or something?

I tried:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"window.resizeBy(0,%d);", TOOLBAR_HEIGHT] ];
```

but it didn't do anything.

Any pointers welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here- leaving the question open as it may be useful to others.

[How to increase the page height by X pixels by using only javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799743/how-to-increase-the-page-height-by-x-pixels-by-using-only-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the UIWebView to display HTML, I would argue that it's cleaner to fix this with CSS:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```